# Python: Finding symmetries in list of lists

Tags: python, list, search, indexing

I'm having a problem with 'symmetries' and I hope you can help.

I have a list which looks like

```
list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,6,8,10,12],[1,4,5,2,3,6],[1,2,3,4,9,3]]
```

and I want to identify symmetries of each element in this list. In this example if I look at the first element `(= i)` in the list and switch `i[1:3]` with `i[3:5]`, then I want to search the rest of the list for matches. We can see that the `list[3]` matches `i` after the switch. 
Can you help me write a fast solution for this? For example: 
I have a function to switch elements which looks like:

```
def switch(i):
    i[1:3], i[3:5] = i[3:5],i[1:3]
return i
```

and then I have a loop which looks like

```
no_sym = []
for i in list:
    sym = [x for x in list if x not in no_sym and not no_sym.append(switch(i))]
    continue
```

but this is not working for me. 
Help!

Comment: `switch([1,2,3,4,5,6])` returns `[1,2,5,6,3,4]`, which is not matched by any element. Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: You're right, apologies. I changed the example. I checked that the switch I have has the right indexes. Still not working.

Comment: I see you accepted my answer (which I'm grateful for) when there was still a bug due to `switch` modifying its argument. Please see the corrected answer.

Comment: Ah, nice catch. I will make a copy of the argument list, I see that this is safest. But I wonder, if we increment through the list, never returning to one in which we're already switched, then does it matter?

Comment: If that is the case, it doesn't matter. But it's easy to forget to check whether that *is* the case (that's why I had the bug, after all), and if you do check, you may get it wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have `append` in this line:

```
sym = [x for x in list if x not in no_sym and not no_sym.append(switch(i))]
```

`foo.append(bar)` returns `None`, and so the code is equivalent to `[x for x in list if x not in no_sym and not None]`, which allows every item not in `no_sym` to make it into `sym`.

Also, your `swtich` function actually modifies its arguments, which is probably no what you want. Check:

```
>>> ls = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,4,6,8,10,12], [1,4,5,2,3,6], [1,2,3,4,9,3]]
>>> switch(ls[0]) == ls[2]  # seems harmless
True
>>> switch(ls[0]) == ls[2]  # but ls[0] has been modified, so the next test fails
False
```

To avoid this, `switch` should make a copy of the argument list:

```
def switch(ls):
    copy_ls = ls[:]
    copy_ls[1:3], copy_ls[3:5] = copy_ls[3:5], copy_ls[1:3]
    return copy_ls
```

Now if you want every item and its "symmetrical" brother as a tuple in `sym`, this will work:

```
>>> ls = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,4,6,8,10,12], [1,4,5,2,3,6], [1,2,3,4,9,3]]
>>> sym = [(x, switch(x)) for x in ls if switch(x) in ls[ls.index(x)+1:]]
>>> sym
[([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6])]
```

Also you should probably not use `list` as a variable name because it would shadow a builtin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you not write the switch right.And I exactly do not understand why 
you use (not no_sym.append(switch(i))).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it seems that you assume the index starts with 1. Actually, the index starts with 0. Therefore, your `switch` function should look like

```
def switch(i):
    i[1:3], i[3:5] = i[3:5], i[1:3]
return i
```

Also, you need to provide more concrete definition of your 'symmetries'. Is your definition is something like 'tuples a and b are symmetry if len(a) = len(b) and either a[i] == b[i] && a[-(i+1)] == b[-(i+1)] or a[i] == b[-(i+1)] && a[-(i+1)]==b[i] for i >=0 and i

Comment: Yes, apologies. I changed the indexes 15 mins ago.
By symmetries, I just mean some portion of each element switched with another portion of the element.

Comment: Then I think your switch function is not enough. You should test if len(a) = len(b) and either a[i] == b[i] && a[-(i+1)] == b[-(i+1)] or a[i] == b[-(i+1)] && a[-(i+1)]==b[i] for i >=0 and i < len(a)/2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want. I'm not sure if I understood what did you mean by "symmetry"

```
_list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,6,8,10,12],[1,4,5,2,3,6],[1,2,3,4,9,3]]

def switch(i):
     result = i[:]
     result[1:3], result[3:5] = result[3:5], result[1:3]
     return result

sym = [(x, switch(x)) for x in _list if switch(x) in _list]

print sym
```

> > [([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6]), ([1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]